# Understanding the output of durbinWatsonTest() in r

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

So I passed my `lm` model in `durbinWatsonTest` and got this result,

```
lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value
1      -0.3068183      2.444027   0.278
 Alternative hypothesis: rho != 0
```

I know that Durbin Watson Test is used to find if there is autocorrelation in the data. But can someone please explain my result, specially "D-W Statistic = 2.444", "p-value = 0.278" and "rho != 0".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It test not for any kind of autocorrelation but just for that at lag 1. In particular, in X<sub>t</sub> = rho X<sub>t-1</sub> + e<sub>t</sub> it tests whether rho = 0 (the null hypothesis). So, computing the [D-W statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic#Computing_and_interpreting_the_Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic) leads to the statistic value 2.444 and p-value 0.27, where with the latter you typically say that the null cannot be rejected. That is, we cannot reject the null that there is no first order autocorrelation.

Comment: @javan.rajpopat, does that answer your question?